# gradle build throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: gradle

Everytime I do a gradle build or a ./gradlew build I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred waiting for process 'Gradle build daemon' to complete.
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:231)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:355)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2065175016
        at java.lang.String.regionMatches(String.java:1287)
        at java.text.DecimalFormat.applyPattern(DecimalFormat.java:3376)
        at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:464)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getInstance(NumberFormatProviderImpl.java:180)
        at sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getNumberInstance(NumberFormatProviderImpl.java:149)
        at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:875)
        at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:861)
        at java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(NumberFormat.java:469)
        at java.util.Scanner.useLocale(Scanner.java:1186)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:540)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:563)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonOutputConsumer.start(DaemonOutputConsumer.java:50)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$CompositeStreamsHandler.start(DefaultExecHandle.java:423)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:74)
        ... 7 more
```

This is happening for all projects. I am on an Ubuntu system.

my gradle -v output is

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-12 11:33:27 UTC
Revision:     76c9179ea9bddc32810f9125ad97c3315c544919

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.4.0-137-generic amd64
```

Comment: the error seems to come from  your Locale configuration: what is the output of the shell command `locale` on this server?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, the locale output is......`LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 |
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en |
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8" |
LC_ALL= 
`